# Performance impact with dask multiple processes no-nanny

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I notice a 5/6 times performance degradation using dask workers with processes only and no-nanny versus with nanny. Is this expected behaviour?

I want to run dask without a nanny due to state in the worker. I appreciate that having state in workers is not desirable but its beyond my control (3rd party library).

Alternative if I run dask workers with a nanny can I capture worker failures/restarts and reinitialise the worker?

Answer (score 2):

A Nanny process just starts a `dask-worker` process, and then watches it, restarting it if it falls over.  It should not affect performance at all.  If you do not have a nanny then you can not capture worker failures or restarts.  This is the role of the nanny.